# Localtunnel on ASP.NET Core comes with error 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: asp.net-core, localtunnel

I'am trying to run my ASP.NET Core localhost app with **localtunnel** for debugging purpose.  And I'm running my ASP Core with Kestrel (I've tried to run it trough IIS too, same result) and enter this command on cmd `"-p 5001 -s someName -o"` and comes with error `"504 Gateway Time-out"`. I'm sure **localtunnel** works fine, because I was able to run it with my express.js demo, but there is some error when I try to run it on asp core. So my question is:

How can I run my ASP.NET Core app with **localtunnel**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out. All i need to do was to disable SSL certificate. From Visual studio

**Right click on the project -> Properties -> Debug -> unmark "Enable SSL" field**

and run project on IIS server with command:

`lt -p 58389 -l localhost -s someName -o`

Comment: It's not obvious why, but the "-l localhost" optional parameter is required.

Comment: ngrok has the same issue. ASP.NET and IIS require that you specify that the host header is localhost for tunnelling

Answer (score 0):

https://conveyor.cloud/ is the best solution I have found for this problem.

Comment: Just note: conveyor.cloud works only in Visual Studio. It does not have command line options nor can it run other types of applications besides ASP.NET to my knowledge.